How to copy file from local appdata to temp in C#?
I'm trying to create app that needs files from local appdata and I edit it for app, so I copy it to temp folder. C# can't copy it because "Acces denied".
I've already tried to create manifest with modifying requestedExecutionLevel and disable UAC.
Edit: my code
public void CopyChromeVersion()
{
    if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{name}_lddata")))
    {
        File.Copy(file + "\\Last Version", tmpPath + $"\\chrome_last_version");
    }
}

My app.manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>



Does it still fail if started as admin? Are you trying to copy data out of a user folder that is not the user that elevated?

Can we see your code?

By default %LOCALAPPDATA% and %TEMP% have the same access rights. %PROGRAMDATA% not but is also used as a common storage path for apps

The question makes little sense to me. Both local appdata and temp should be writable for a normal user. If you run your app as a restricted permissions, or have some other non-standard configuration, that needs to be mentioned in the question.
